# Unable to access jarfile using crontab

Tags: java

I have two jar file that I want to run using crontab. Let's say that there is an A and B jarfile. When I want to run the crontab for the A jarfile, the crontab work fine. But when I want to run for the B jarfile, the crontab is unable to access the jarfile. Where could go wrong with this? Is the problem is on the jarfile, or on the crontab settings?

Here is my crontab setting

0  12,14  *  *  * root /root/folderjarfile/runx.sh >> /root/folderjarfile/nohup.out

Comment: Is these jar files have the same owner and permission?

Comment: @waxtah how to check this one?

Comment: I would log stderr as well as stdout e.g. /path/myscript 2>&1 >>/tmp/my.log

Comment: Can you run the B.jar file outside of cron (e.g. from the command line)? To check ownership and permission use ```ls -l A.jar B.jar```

Comment: @GMc I can run the B.jar properly without using cron at the command line

Comment: So it is not lkikely to be a corruption of B.jar (because it works outside of cron). Given that fact, it likely to be some sort of environmental issue. e.g. there is a variable setting in your interactive terminal session (where B.jar works) that differs from the cron environment. My answer below talks about how to look at the environment in cron and compare it to the environment in your interactive session.Try to look for java differences (classpath, java_home, java version etc) between the cron environment and your interactive environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be problem with your jar file. Possible options to find it out.

1. Run that jar without crontab means submit java -cp jarPath main-method
2. If option-1 works fine then, You have to restart your cron tab

   ```
   Stop Cron Job: /etc/init.d/crond stop
   Start Cron Job: /etc/init.d/crond start
   ```

Comment: is it the same command like systemctl stop/start crond? because I can't find /etc/init.d/crond in my server..

Comment: I doubt very much that the cron daemon needs restarting. I strongly suspect an environment issue in the invocation (from experience)

Comment: @Brian I tested it in AWS and restart helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Cron usually does not run your profile. So you only get a basic environment.

try putting the following in your runx.sh

```sh
env |sort >/tmp/my_cron_env.txt
```

Let your job run and have a look at your PATH and other variables. You will probably find things that you expect to be there (e.g. JAVA_HOME) are missing.

Comment: So, the things that I expect to be there will be noted at the my_cron_env.txt? or I still need to make some configuration at the txt file?

Comment: The above line will print out your environment when running under the control of cron. You will likely find that the settings are much simpler than what you have in your terminal session. You can do the same thing (e.g. ```env | sort > /tmp/myterm_env.txt```) in your terminal session and compare the two files.

Comment: Actually I just re-read your post, you have one that works and one that doesn't. So this might not be your problem. Can you add your shell scripts to your original question?

Comment: Is there an error message generated from your script? **Make sure you add 2>>&1 to the end of your cron job command** i.e. ```/root/folderjarfile/runx.sh >> /root/folderjarfile/nohup.out 2>&1``` This will capture any error messages in your output log file (nohup.out).

Comment: Oh, do not forget to use crontab -e to edit the crontab file (i.e. the file shown in your post) or yast or similar. If you simply edit the crontab file directly with vi or a notepad program, you will need to signal cron that you have changed it's configuration file. If you are not sure what any of this means, then edit your file however you do currently and then reboot.